Powershell & bash: get all files matching a directory in the path and file name
I'm looking to operate on all the files in a directory I have that are within some directory (e.g. .../bin/.../myfile.txt), where each ... can be any number of directories deep. In nu shell, I can do this directly using ** (the recursive wildcard) by e.g. doing:
mycommand **/bin/**/myfile.txt

I tried using Get-ChildItem as follows:
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Filter myfile.txt

But this gets all instances of myfile.txt, not just the ones nested under a bin/ directory. It also seems like ** is not a thing in powershell, so that's not an option. Is there any straightforward way to do get what I want?
Similarly, what's the way to do the same thing in bash (again, it seems like ** is not available to me)?

In bash, you have to enable ** with shopt -s globstar.

you could filter it in a where statement. something like Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Filter myfile.txt | Where{$_.FullName -like "$PWD*\bin\*myfile.txt"} Which would filter for paths that start with $PWD (the PowerShell Working Directory), have a folder named bin somewhere in the path, and end with the file in question. Yes, it is redundant to have to put your file twice, but it's faster that way.

It's a little clunky, but one can do the following in powershell:
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Directory -Filter bin | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter myfile.txt

The first command finds all the bin/ directories, and then the second one looks within those directories and looks recursively for the file you want. You can chain this together for any number of directories in between.

If you're going to do that use the -directory parameter on the first Get-ChildItem so the file system provider doesn't return any files. You could add -file to the second one, but that would only avoid it returning a folder named myfile.txt,  which seems unlikely unless you're looking for files that don't have an extension.

Good suggestion! Will edit that in.

Similarly using find you can do
find . -type d -name bin -exec find {} -name myfile.txt \;

to list all files named myfile.txt inside any bin subdir.
